# Is there a way to set custom file properties in mercurial?

Tags: svn, mercurial

Is there a feature in mercurial similar to subversion's [propset](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.0/re23.html) command?

What I really want is info about each file indicating whether it has code reviewed and QA'd.  When a product is released every file in the tip will have these attributes/properties set.

Comment: Isn't this something better done in bug/issue tracking software?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not.  Commits in mercurial are indelible, so no command can go back and alter them.  Properties would have to be stored in separate meta-data file(s) which would also be version tracked (sort of like the .hgtags file).  One could build an extension to do that but every property alteration would put another changeset in your history.